# using HTML tags in basic Javascript that calls an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

## The Problem

I'm new to this...

I have a some basic HTML that contains a circular `div`, that contains a child circular `div` that has an image using the CSS `background-image`, a `h1` and `p` tag is shown using the `:hover` selector.

This block of code is repeated twice and wrapped in a `section` tag like so:

```
<section class="col-4">

        <div class="img-wrapper">           
            <a href="#">                
                <div class="outta-circle">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h1 id="news-title-1"></h1>
                        <p>Read more...</p>
                    </div>  
                    <div id="circle1"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="outta-circle">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h1 id="news-title-2"></h1>
                        <p>Read more...</p>
                    </div>      
                    <div id="circle2"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

</section>
```

This is the first time I've written Javascript, but I use some basic code to deal with an array that holds news article content (I haven't looked at using the likes of MySQL yet), and some code to deal with changing the `background-image` property's `url()` attribute, which seems to work:

```
var articleArray = [

{img: "img/img-01.jpg", title: "Article Name", content: "This is the content coming from javascript", date: "27/6/2013"},

{img: "img/img-02.jpg", title: "Article Two Name", content: "This is also content coming from javascript", date: "28/6/2013"}

];

S('circle1').backgroundImage = 'url('+articleArray[articleArray.length - 2]["img"]+')';
S('circle2').backgroundImage = 'url('+articleArray[articleArray.length - 1]["img"]+')';

var newsTitle = articleArray[articleArray.length - 2]["title"];
var newsTitle2 = articleArray[articleArray.length - 1]["title"];

O('news-title-1').innerHTML = newsTitle;
O('news-title-2').innerHTML = newsTitle2;
```

I have some experience with PHP, and usually I would write a function that parses (that's the right word yeah?) the HTML with the PHP using a `foreach` loop eliminating the need for the duplicate ID tags like `circle1` and `circle2`. I've gone down the Javascript route to because I couldn't work out how to change the `background-image` property's `url()` attribute dynamically, and it's been good to finally look at some Javascript :)

## What I'd like

Some advice on best practises so the above code is presented correctly and so I can loop through the array incorporating the HTML, placing the content where it needs to be

Please bear in mind my knowledge is limited, I haven't been doing this for long, so it would be appreciated if any help is put down in layman terms.....many thanks!!!

Comment: If you're open to javascript libraries that will make your life easier, take a look at jQuery.

Comment: Cheers @RobW I'll take a look, although I'm on day 1 of looking at this stuff. I feel getting grips with the basics of JS first would be beneficial....but then I might be barking up the wrong tree!!

Comment: I recommend against looking into a library first. Learn what javascript does and how it interacts with the dom. That way when your library breaks or doesn't do what you want it to, your not stuck up a creek without a paddle.

Comment: Cheers for the advice @ryan sounds like a safe bet